# Show a word in the middle of Page - Pascal

Tags: delphi, pascal

I have a very simple question. Look t my code which is written in Pascal:

```
Program Example;
Begin
Writeln('Question');
Readln;
End.
```

I want to show "Question" word in the middle of Page, How to do that?

Comment: Do you mean middle of the screen ?

Comment: When I run this code, a console application will be opened and as you know background is black ! I want to show this word in the middle of this black background :) any way?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Perhaps something like this (I assume you are actually using Delphi or something compatible):

```
var
  csbi: TConsoleScreenBufferInfo;
  crd: TCoord;
  h: THandle;

const
  S = 'Hello World!';

begin
  h := GetStdHandle(STD_OUTPUT_HANDLE);
  GetConsoleScreenBufferInfo(h, csbi);
  crd.Y := csbi.dwSize.Y div 2;
  crd.X := (csbi.dwSize.X - length(S)) div 2;
  SetConsoleCursorPosition(h, crd);
  Write(S);
  Readln;
```

Comment: Hi, Thanks for reply, but it gave me some errors. 1-Identifier not found TCONSOLESCREENBUFFERINFO  2- Identifier not found TCOORD. so what should I do?

Answer (score 1):

You could try my [Console](http://rvelthuis.de/programs/console.html) unit. It will do this and a few things more. It comes with a simple demo displaying the capabilities.

Answer (score 1):

If you're using console mode at 80 columns by 25 rows (lines), you could do it even easier.  No need for fancy code, just assume the 12th line (since 25 div 2 is 12.5, I use 12).  Note that I am just using Borland Pascal for this...

```
Uses CRT;

Const
  YourText = 'Hello World!';

Begin
  GotoXY(40 - Length(YourText) div 2, 12);
  WriteLn(YourText);
End.
```

Hope that helps.

Comment: Hi, Yours is great too, small code which do the same as the previous code in previous answer. Well Done Man ;)

Comment: FWIW, there is no CRT unit for Delphi. But my Console unit mimics it as well as possible.